# What is viewstate in JSF, and how is it used?

Tags: java, jsf, richfaces, myfaces

In JSF, there is a viewstate associated with each page, which is passed back and forth with submits etc.

I know that viewstate is calculated using the states of the various controls on the page, and that you can store it either client side or server side.

The question is: how is this value used? Is it used to validate the values sent at submit, to ensure that the same request is not sent twice?

Also, how is it calculated - I realise that richfaces may be calculated differently from myfaces, but an idea would be nice.

Thanks.

Comment: There is currently some debate about the view state in the JSF community. See this bug report: http://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES_SPEC_PUBLIC-1055

Answer (score 29, accepted):

> The question is: how is this value
>   used? Is it used to validate the
>   values sent at submit, to ensure that
>   the same request is not sent twice?

The original reason why the viewstate exists is because HTTP is stateless. The state of the components across requests need to be maintained one way or the other. Either you store the state in memory on the server and bind it to the session, or serialize/deserialize it in the request/response each time.

AFAIK, the viewstate is not used to detect double submit, but it could if you attach a timestamp or something similar to it.

The viewstate can also be encrypted to make sure the client doesn't alter it.

> Also, how is it calculated - I realise
>   that richfaces may be calculated
>   differently from myfaces, but an idea
>   would be nice.

Each component is responsible to persist its state with `saveState` and `restoreState` (see this [tutorial](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jsf4/)). So different component suites result in different view state. Similarly, different JSF implementations might result in different view state.

Comment: "Either you store the state in memory on the server and bind it to the session, or serialize/deserialize it in the request/response each time." How do I choose one over another?

Comment: @KorayTugay there is a param javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD in the config

Comment: "The state of the components across requests need to be maintained one way or the other." This statement seems not to be correct. At least it is not explained why one need to maintain component state. Moreover JSF 2.2 introduced stateless views.

Answer (score 13):

If you're familiar with JavaScript, you can think of a JSF component tree a bit like a HTML DOM where the HTML page defines the initial state but you can alter it at runtime.

The view technology (usually JSP or Facelets) defines the initial state, but after that it can be manipulated programatically. For example, you could add a [component](http://java.sun.com/javaee/6/docs/api/javax/faces/component/html/HtmlCommandButton.html) or set a [property](http://java.sun.com/javaee/6/docs/api/javax/faces/component/html/HtmlInputText.html#setStyle(java.lang.String)). In order for this to work properly, the view state must be persisted between requests.

The view state is divided into two parts. The first defines the structure of the component tree:

```
UIView
 - UIForm
    - UICommand
    - UIInput
```

The second part defines the state of the components. These are separate due to components like UIData, where it is possible for children to have (for example) per row state. This is marshalled/unmarshalled via the [StateHolder](http://java.sun.com/javaee/6/docs/api/javax/faces/component/StateHolder.html) mechanisms.