# i am getting java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException when executing jmeter scritps in wildfly8 java8 and jsf application

Tags: jmeter

I am using Jmeter for load test. Our configuration is wildfly8.0 with java8 and Jmeter 2.13. My problem is existing script not working I am getting the following error

```
18:01:34,412 SEVERE [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.context] (default task-2) java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:653)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:429)
    at javax.faces.component.AttachedObjectListHolder.restoreState(AttachedObjectListHolder.java:166)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.restoreState(UIComponentBase.java:1611)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletPartialStateManagementStrategy$2.visit(FaceletPartialStateManagementStrategy.java:380)
    at com.sun.faces.component.visit.FullVisitContext.invokeVisitCallback(FullVisitContext.java:151)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1689)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1700)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1700)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1700)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletPartialStateManagementStrategy.restoreView(FaceletPartialStateManagementStrategy.java:367)
    at com.sun.faces.application.StateManagerImpl.restoreView(StateManagerImpl.java:138)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.ViewHandlingStrategy.restoreView(ViewHandlingStrategy.java:123)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.restoreView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:585)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.restoreView(MultiViewHandler.java:150)
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.restoreView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:353)
    at org.richfaces.application.GlobalResourcesViewHandler.restoreView(GlobalResourcesViewHandler.java:179)
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.restoreView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:353)
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.restoreView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:353)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.execute(RestoreViewPhase.java:197)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.doPhase(RestoreViewPhase.java:121)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:646)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:130)
    at com.boeing.Wsrd.web.filter.ClearCache.doFilter(ClearCache.java:44)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:132)
    at com.boeing.ccl.auth.web.UserFilter.doFilter(UserFilter.java:68)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:132)
    at com.boeing.Wsrd.web.filter.WsrdRoles.actionForSessionBems(WsrdRoles.java:335)
    at com.boeing.Wsrd.web.filter.WsrdRoles.getUserDetails(WsrdRoles.java:275)
    at com.boeing.Wsrd.web.filter.WsrdRoles.doFilter(WsrdRoles.java:128)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:132)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:85)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:61)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:56)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:45)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:63)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:58)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:70)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.SecurityInitialHandler.handleRequest(SecurityInitialHandler.java:76)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:261)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:247)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:76)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:166)
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:197)
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:759)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

please any one suggest me to resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you've not correlated (or correlated incorrectly) [javax.faces.ViewState](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2910741/what-is-viewstate-in-jsf-and-how-is-it-used) dynamic parameter.

1. Add i.e. [Regular Expression Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor) to first request
2. Configure it like:

   - Reference Name: anything meaningful, i.e. `viewstate`
   - Regular Expression: `input type="hidden" name="javax\.faces\.ViewState" id="javax\.faces\.ViewState" value="([^"]+)".*/>` (or other matching)
   - Template: `$1$`
3. Replace recorded "Viestate" parameter value next request with `${viewstate}`

You might also need to add [HTTP Cookie Manager](http://Using%20the%20HTTP%20Cookie%20Manager%20in%20JMeter) in order to deal with [JSESSIONID](http://www.cs-repository.info/2014/07/understanding-jsessionid.html) and other cookies.

Comment: Hi Dimitri. thanks for your reply. I followed same steps as you mentioned above, still I am getting same error.