# javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException with JMeter in JSF Application

Tags: java, jsf, jmeter

I am new in JMeter.

I am using JMeter to test scenario in JSF application, the scenario to login the application and open crud page (issue_warning_create.jsf) to create record in database and it is successful with my browser but when I test the scenario with JMeter it fails with this exception:

> javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException: viewId:/secure/adt/fin/issue_warning_create.jsf could not be restored.

I noticed that JMeter use different session id than session id get from response. I tried to listen logout to terminate session and make new request with new session in JMeter but also give me the same exception. I add http cookie manager and xpath extractor to get view state as in images:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: I updated my answer following your additional details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You must add a [Cookie Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager)
- You must also correlate JSF View State using Regex Extractor:

> Regex : input type="hidden" name="javax.faces.ViewState" id="javax.faces.ViewState" value="([^"]+)".*/
>
> varName: jsfViewState
>
> Template : $1$

You'll have then to use ${jsfViewState} wherever it is present.

See:

- https://wiki.apache.org/myfaces/PerformanceTestingWithJMeter

**In your test, replace -1 in XPath Extractor by 1**

Comment: Thanks very much this fixed my problem

Comment: Please UBIK LOAD PACK this page have some lists to select items and then submit to db,when I run scenario in jmetere with 5 users its ok but when I run it with 10 users give me java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0. why?

Answer (score 0):

[JSESSIONID](http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2012/08/what-is-jsessionid-in-j2ee-web.html) can operate in 2 modes:

1. As a [HTTP Cookie](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies), in this case HTTP Cookie Manager will do the trick
2. As a part of the URL. If your application appends `JSESSIONID` to the request URL you need to use [HTTP URL Re-writing Modifier](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-the-http-url-re-writing-modifier) to automatically handle this value and amend your URLs accordingly.

With regards to [Viewstate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2910741/what-is-viewstate-in-jsf-and-how-is-it-used), your XPath Extractor seems to be correct, however in case of not very well-formed XHTML you might need to tick `Use Tidy` box. Double check your `myViewState` variable value using [Debug Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Debug_Sampler) and [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener combination.